# Is it possible to search for stored \u000 (null character) data in DocumentDB?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following data stored in DocumentDB:

```
{
"DocumentDbTest_AllFieldTypes": {
     "@numeric": "-978623478.23434",
     "@string": "test\u0000",
     "@boolset": "test|test1",
     "@date": "2010/12/24",
     "@datetime": "2010/12/24 09:12:34",
     "@time": "09:12:34",
     "@richtext": "<html onload='alert(3)'>test</html>",
     "@version": "2015-08-27T13:17:30:975.230",
     "typename": "DocumentDbTest_AllFieldTypes",
     }
 "id": "56177058-eb54-4b4d-a4ee-45b9603d4c2c"
}
```

But when I search for it I am not getting the data back.

```
SELECT * FROM root.DocumentDbTest_AllFieldTypes c 
WHERE c["@string"] =  "test\u0000"
```

Does anyone know how to search for the \u000 (null character) data or similar data in DocumentDB?
[image: Data with \u000 (null character) in DocumentDB]

Comment: i'll look in to this in a second, it should work.

Comment: just some observations; why is your numeric actually a string? and why are your fields prefixed with @? Is this on purpose? I noticed typename is not. this won't be causing the issue, am just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been confirmed as a limitation. The code assumes null-terminated strings and hence would consider “test\u0000” the same as ‘test’. In short, \u0000 is currently not a supported string character in a query.

We will work on a future fix.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.